# How do i inject a service to another service in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have `DataService` and `StateContainer`.
`DataService` is responsible to obtain and provide data with respect to state changes. `StateContainer` is responsible as states changes, it registeres as a singleton.

I want `DataService` can access `StateContainer` public property. such that it could provide the data accordingly, How may I do so? How should I register `DataService`?

Comment: You should just be able to add the service you want to use in the constructor of the service you want to use it from. As long as the service has been properly registered in DI it will be accessible in the constructor of the consuming service.

Answer (score 4):

Just register your DataService in the DI System

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataService>();
```

Now you should be able to Access the StateCointainer via DI if you inject it via the Constructor.

```cs
    public class DataService
{

    private readonly StateContainer _stateContainer;
    
    public DataService(StateContainer stateContainer)
    {
        _stateContainer = stateContainer;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's implied in your answer, but `StateContainer` must also be registered with DI or you will get a runtime error.